# Get all %(name)s placeholders in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string that contains `%(name)s` placeholders and I would like to get all the names, for example: `This is a %(name)s example string %(foo)s I would like %(bar)s to extract all the placeholders from %(place)s`

I would like to get a list containing `name`, `foo`, `bar`, `place`

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "This is a %(name)s example string %(foo)s I would like %(bar)s to extract all the placeholders from %(place)s"
print(re.findall(r"%\((.*?)\)", s))
# --> ['name', 'foo', 'bar', 'place']
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good use for [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "This is a %(name)s example string %(foo)s I would like %(bar)s to extract all the placeholders from %(place)s"
>>> re.findall(r'%\((.+?)\)', string)
['name', 'foo', 'bar', 'place']
```

`%\((.+?)\)` means starting with `%(`, ending with the next `)`, capture everything in between.